# Customizing AWT ScrollPane

Tags: java, awt, scrollpane

I have an AWT canvas (3rd party library) that displays some information. I need to display a scroll pane over top of it. Since the canvas is AWT, I need to use a ScrollPane instead of a JScrollPane. I'd like to give the scrollpane a rounded border - is that at all possible in AWT? Or is there any way I can use a JScrollPane on top of the canvas and still have it show up (I think the latest version of Java supports better mixing of lightweight/heavyweight components, but let's assume that's not an option).

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: You mentioned popups in one of your comments - can you provide further details? PopupMenu? JPopupMenu?  Popup/PopupFactory?

Comment: In my application, you can click on items on a display. When the item is clicked on, information about it pops up. There can be a lot of info, so I want to put it in a scroll pane. The item being clicked must be on a 3D canvas, so I'm trying to display scrollable text about the item. Ideally I'd like to customize the border of the popup to give it a "rounded" effect.

Comment: Well, you described what you want - but I can't determine if what you want is possible because I don't know what type of components/classes are being used to generate the popup.  It could be painted directly on the 3D canvas or could be using one of the classes I mentioned in my previous comment...  Do you have the code where the popup is launched?  Or how you provide content for the popup?

Comment: Currently, I just create a ScrollPane and add it to the canvas and set its bounds, however, I'm writing the code to do that so I can make it do whatever I want...

Comment: You're already going about it the way you need to. If you want to have rounded corners though, your best bet is probably to create your own AWT component with a ScrollBar inside that adds a border margin, and paints transparent borders. ... Which gives me an idea, if AWT has borders, you may be able to specify a very custom border that doesn't paint all of the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

"Since the canvas is AWT, I need to use a ScrollPane instead of a JScrollPane."

Why is this? I think you can use a JScrollPane.

`Canvas extends java.awt.Component`, and there is a constructor `JScrollPane(java.awt.component component)`

Comment: The canvas isn't going in the scrollpane. The scrollpane is part of a popup component that sits on top of the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I initially toyed around with the idea of using a `JScrollPane` inside a `JPopupMenu` with `setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false)`.  However, this pops up in a new top-level window above the component - so any rounded borders are drawn on top of the top-level window.  It looks like a gray rectangle with the `JScrollPane` drawn on top with rounded borders.

Then I thought about putting the `ScrollPane` into a `Panel` that could handle drawing the rounded border around it.  Unfortunately, AWT components don't have the `setOpaque()` property like Swing components do, so they are rectangular. I could copy the same background color as the parent, but if you wanted to display this on top of some data, it would be pretty obvious.

The compromise approach I finally came up with was to have the `Container` component paint the border around the `ScrollPane` child.  This is definitely more of a hack-y solution, but it's the only one so far that's worked... here's the final code:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.ScrollPane;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class CanvasPopup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Frame f = new Frame("CanvasPopup");
        final ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane();
        final Panel c = new Panel(null) {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

                if (scroll.isVisible()) {
                    g.setColor(Color.RED);
                    Rectangle bounds = scroll.getBounds();
                    g.fillRoundRect(bounds.x - 10, bounds.y - 10, 
                            bounds.width + 20, bounds.height + 20, 15, 15);
                }
            }
        };

        final List list = new List();
        for (int i = 0; i<100; i++) {
            list.add("Item " + i);
        }
        scroll.add(list);
        scroll.setBounds(75, 75, 150, 150);
        scroll.setVisible(false);
        c.add(scroll);

        c.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (!scroll.isVisible()) {
                    scroll.setLocation(e.getPoint());
                }
                scroll.setVisible(!scroll.isVisible());
                c.repaint();
            }
        });
        f.add(c);

        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```